# Is the direction of a laser flash affected by the source's movement direction?

Tags: special-relativity, visible-light

Supposing a spaceship is moving in space in a straight line at very high speed, with a laser source on top of it flashing straight up (i.e. orthogonal to the spaceship's movement direction). Would the photons of the flash "inherit" the source's "lateral" movement and so travel continuously above the source (as if someone inside the ship would see the laser flash going straight up continuously) or would they just move straight up from the point of emission without any lateral movement (in which case someone inside the ship would see the falsh going straight up but staying continuously behind the ship)?

Answer (score 0):

If the spaceship is moving with a constant speed with respect to another inertial observer not in the ship, then occupants of the ship would see the laser light moving straight up from the ship, as in your first scenario. From the point of view of the observer outside the ship, the light would travel at an angle with respect to the direction of motion. Check out the diagram in this derivation of time dilation in special relativity:
[How special relativity works](https://science.howstuffworks.com/science-vs-myth/everyday-myths/relativity10.htm)

A basic postulate is that the laws of physics are the same in all inertial reference frames. So the occupant of the ship cannot do any experiment to prove he is moving at any particular speed. Thus, if he shines the laser straight up, it has to move straight up from the ship, otherwise he would be able to prove he is in uniform motion.

Comment: Thanks for that. So can we conclude from your answer that light shares the inertia of its source? Otherwise, what could possibly cause the laser flash to have this lateral/orthogonal velocity component seen from the viewpoint of the inertial observer outside the ship?

Comment: That is a very good question. If the ship occupant threw a ball up, the outside observer would say that the ball had momentum in the direction of the ship's motion by virtue of its being on the ship and it retained this momentum once tossed, thus the oblique path it takes. Maybe someone else can comment here - how does the outside observer explain the oblique path of light? Does the light carry the momentum of the ship's motion?